# Capture command output in variable and suppress it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I want to capture output of the following command in a shell script:

```
echo "User-Name=root,User-Password=root123" | radclient 192.168.19.104 auth testing123
```

I have a shell script as follows:

```
FILE=server

        while IFS="\t" read -r ip key;
        do
                case "$ip" in
                        "0.0.0.0") continue ;;
                esac
                echo "User-Name=root,User-Password=root123" | radclient $ip auth $key

        done < "$FILE"
        exit 1
```

**Edit: Removed the extra quotes and it works.**

Now, Upon running the command:

```
echo "User-Name=root,User-Password=root123" | radclient 192.168.19.104 auth testing123
```

It returns following output: (Actually the **radclient** returns the following output).

```
Received response ID 1, code 2, length = 33
    Reply-Message = "Hello, root"
```

**How to capture output from the command.**

Edit: As per Answer below I used:

```
OUTPUT=`echo "User-Name=$username,User-Password=$passwd" | radclient $ip auth $key`
```

This captures returned string in OUTPUT. **However it also prints the output on screen.**

How can we suppress output of radclient from printing on screen as well as  store the ouput in OUTPUT.

Comment: Your "extra" quotes end up quoting the `|` from the shell and making it a string argument to `echo`. Remove them. (You can't nest quotes like that. They start at the first quotation mark and end at the next unescaped quotation mark.) Use exactly the command you wrote at the start.

Comment: @EtanReisner. Oh yes. that fixed it and now it works. So I edited it for a more complex doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the output in a variable like this:

```
OUTPUT=$(echo "User-Name=root,User-Password=root123" | radclient $ip auth $key)
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

Comment: Yes that works, however the output of radclient command also get print on screen, can we suppress output of radclient and only store in OUTPUT.

Comment: So you only want to see `Hello, root` ?

Comment: No I don't want to see anything from that return string. But the return string should be stored in OUTPUT as before.

Comment: If `var=$(echo ... | radclient ...)` outputs data to the screen then it is writing to standard error instead of standard output and you need to add `2>&1` to the end of the inner command. And anything that hits the screen there will **not** be in `$OUTPUT` (until you add the redirection).